# Radio button text doesn't get displayed properly when setting it's font to an italic font

Tags: c++, c, winapi

When setting the font of a radio button to an italic font, the radio button text doesn't get displayed all the way. It gets clipped on the right side. It only happens when visual styles are on. I am testing this on Windows XP. How do you fix this?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>


#pragma comment(linker, \
  "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' "\
  "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' "\
  "version='6.0.0.0' "\
  "processorArchitecture='*' "\
  "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' "\
  "language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HFONT hFont = 0;
    static HWND hBtn = 0;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            int nHeight = -MulDiv(8, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
            hFont = CreateFont(nHeight, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, TRUE, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Microsoft Sans Serif");
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

            hBtn = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", L"Hello", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, 
                20, 20, 220, 20, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
            SendMessage(hBtn, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT: //"Hello" gets displayed properly with WM_PAINT but not in radio button
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HFONT hOldFont;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
            TextOut(hdc, 20, 80, L"Hello", 5);
            SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY: 
        DeleteObject(hFont);
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break;

    default: 
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    InitCommonControls();
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"MainClass", L"Hello", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 140, 140, 400, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding a few spaces to the end of the control's label.